# doing a batch update in sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

We have a application which will be reading records from a file and then processing them.  Once processed (doing some calculations) those records need to be written to the database.  The number of records will vary based on what's in the file, is there anyway using asp.net and sql server 2008 to have the update done in one shot, so I am not calling the stored procedure over and over based on the number of records?

I just want to avoid for example reading in 1000 records and for each one calling the stored procedure passing the parameters to insert.  Would prefer if that can be handled all in one shot.

I thought about generating a string with all the values, which I could pass to the proc to execute, but that might involve parsing the string to get the values, so wanted to see if there is a better way.

This application is using asp.net 4.5 and SQL Server 2008, not using Entity Framework or MVC, if that matters.

Comment: When you say "batch update", are you updating the records or inserting them?

Comment: both.  initially the application will read from the file and do a mass insert to get the data in.  future reads will be updates to existing records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways of potentially dealing with this.

If you are doing the processing in your asp application and then only want to insert into SQL Server, one of the fastest ways of getting records into it is with [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx)